# How do I cast this using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following snippet, my question is, how do I cast this using a simplified syntax, maybe using LINQ syntax?

```
 private ObservableCollection<ISelectableItem> GetSelectableUnits(ObservableCollection<Unit> units)
        {
            var selectableUnits = new ObservableCollection<ISelectableItem>();

            units.ToList().ForEach(item=>selectableUnits.Add(new SelectableUnit(item)));

            return selectableUnits;
        }
```

Note:SelectableUnit implements ISelectableItem.

Thanks,
-Mike

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679169.aspx) constructor of `ObservableCollection<T>`, which lets you construct the collection from an existing `IEnumerable<T>`.

In C# 4, you can do:

```
return new ObservableCollection<ISelectableItem>
           (units.Select(item => new SelectableUnit(item)));
```

Because of the [covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx) of the `IEnumerable<T>` interface, an `IEnumerable<SelectableUnit>` can be seen as an `IEnumerable<ISelectableItem>`.

In C# 3, which does not support variance in generic interfaces, you can do:

```
return new ObservableCollection<ISelectableItem>
           (units.Select(item => new SelectableUnit(item)).Cast<ISelectableItem>());
```

(or)

```
 return new ObservableCollection<ISelectableItem>
               (units.Select(item => (ISelectableItem)new SelectableUnit(item)));
```

If you are doing this sort of thing often, consider writing a `ToObservableCollection()` extension- method on `IEnumerable<T>` to let type-inference and/or method-chaining work in your favour.

Answer (score 0):

In C# 3/ .Net 3.5

```
return new ObservableCollection<ISelectableItem>
           (units.Select(item => new SelectableUnit(item)).Cast<ISelectableItem>());
```